# Which one is better, Transform : translate or Position : absolute

Tags: html, css

I just want to know with the experience of the others which solution do you use generally to position an element out of the natural flow? 
 - Transform: translate
 - Position: Absolute.
Thank's :)

Comment: Define 'better'.

Comment: as usual, the answer is "it depends", can you define your specific usecase ?

Answer (score 2):

All depends.

`position:absolute` actually can work together with `transform:translate`. For example, if you want to place a div (dynamic height/width) you can do below:

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <!-- Dynamic content here meaning height and width could change -->
</div>

#mydiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; /* Top of element would appear in the centre */
    left: 50%; /* Left of element would appear in the centre */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Bring the element centre to area centre */
    /* I'm lazy to make above lines cross browser but you shouldn't */
}
```

In above case, if the parent element is the full height and width of the window, the box will stay in the centre.

Hope this give you some inspirations.

Answer (score 0):

```
position : absolute
```

*this does pose issues for responsive pages.